# How to open Google Street View in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I´m trying to open street view in UIWebView but it doesn´t work. I can see just normal maps. How can I solve it? Any other possibilities?

that´s my code:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=bran+castle&sll=44.439972,26.096894&sspn=0.000869,0.003664&ie=UTF8&hq=Bran+Castle&hnear=Bran+Castle,+Strada+General+Traian+Mo%C8%99oiu+nr.+28+E574,+Bran+507025,+Romania&t=k&layer=c&cbll=45.516381,25.368123&panoid=0d7jjq7vdWGTxFyonEKnBQ&cbp=12,209.81,,1,-18.52&ll=45.516381,25.368123&spn=0,0.008444&z=17";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webV loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Give us some more detail.

Comment: I just see a regular 2d map instead of street view :( I really don´t know how to open street view

Comment: This can be done by embedding the html page containing the Google Map control in your app. See 2nd paragraph in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329934/does-mkmapview-support-the-little-man-street-view).

Comment: ok, thanks. I hope it´s gonna work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. U can't achieve this .

see here
but u can like this

http://maps.google.com/?q=Tokyo@35.680,139.769

u can pass this link to ur webview to load it.

see here

[Does MapKit allow for StreetView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817678/does-mapkit-allow-for-streetview)

Comment: thanks for answer but I don´t understand this one:
"see here but u can like this
http://maps.google.com/?q=Tokyo@35.680,139.769"
what is it suppose to mean? Can I use it somehow with street view?
thanks

Comment: u can pass this link to ur webview to load it.click and see whats happening

Answer (score 2):

Try loading this code  for your UIWebview:

```
NSString *latLongString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", latitude, longitude];

[_uiWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name='viewport',user-scalable=no'/><script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'type='text/javascript'></script></head><body onload=\"new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('p'),{position:new google.maps.LatLng(%@)});\" style='padding:0px;margin:0px;'><div id='p' style='height:100%%; width:100%%;'></div></body></html>",latLongString] baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Run the Google map url request in your webView and in webViewDidFinishLoad method add this below line to hide alert.
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementsByClassName('ml-unsupported-link-dialog-container')[0].style.display='none'")

Here is a sample call to load Google StreetView in UIWebView. I used Swift.

```html
let urlAddress = "http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=bran+castle&sll=44.439972,26.096894&sspn=0.000869,0.003664&ie=UTF8&hq=Bran+Castle&hnear=Bran+Castle,+Strada+General+Traian+Mo%C8%99oiu+nr.+28+E574,+Bran+507025,+Romania&t=k&layer=c&cbll=45.516381,25.368123&panoid=0d7jjq7vdWGTxFyonEKnBQ&cbp=12,209.81,,1,-18.52&ll=45.516381,25.368123&spn=0,0.008444&z=17";            
        
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlAddress)!)
        glWebView.loadRequest(request)
```